# Facebook access token with "never-expire"

Tags: facebook, access-token

I'm trying to get a Facebook access token that never expires but I cannot manage to do it. Here is my steps:

1) Use Facebook graph explorer to generate a short live access token with the desired permissions (this token is valid for 1h or so)

2) Get a long live token (2 months expiry time) by manual GET request to
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
client_id=[app-client-id]&client_secret=[app-secret-id]& fb_exchange_token=[short-live-access-token]

3) An this tohttps://graph.facebook.com/[user-id]?fields=access_token&access_token=[long-live-access-token]

but that last steps show an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (access_token) on node type (User)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "DpmM6CyzoAt"
  }
}
```

I have found that last step somewhere on the net so I presume FB must have change something, I have read their api doc but I cannot figure out by what resource they chance the step 3.

Could someone explain me how to get a user access token that never expires ?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User Tokens are never valid forever, an extended one is only valid for 60 days as you have found out already. I assume you want to get an Extended Page Token, that´s how you can get one:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[page-id]?fields=access_token&access_token=[long-live-user-token]
```

Basically, you just need to use a Page ID, it does not work with a User ID.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How exactly can I get the page id? When I said [user-id] I was referring to my Facebook page id (www.facebook.com/[numbers..]

Comment: i am pretty sure you tried with a user profile, that would explain the error message. what is your page link?

Comment: I was a bit confused by what is a page id (I thought it was my user page id) But I got it now.. I have created a Facebook page and took its ID. That made the call work, I have now a never expire token thanks !

Comment: To access your Facebook's Page ID:
Open your Facebook page.
Click the About tab.
Scroll down to the bottom of the Page Info section.
Next to Facebook Page ID, you can find your page ID.